# How to delete Windows XP and integrate its partition to Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, partitioning, windows-xp, resize

I currently have my machine partitioned with Windows 7 & XP; and since XP will soon no longer be officially supported I want to replace that partition with Ubuntu. However I also already  have an Ubuntu OS running on the same drive, is there a way to Integrate the XP partition to already installed Ubuntu system? Or do I need to do a clean Install?

Comment: can you open Gparted (I think it is installed by default on Ubuntu not sure though) and paste a screen shot of how your disk is partitioned?

Comment: Sorry, No, it doesn't appear to be installed. Although I do remember using when I first installed the OS.

Comment: ok, you could install it, it is in the software center. there is also probably a command you can run to give the info, but I don't know what. What I want to know is whether the partitions are located next to each other. in that case it should be quite easy: go in a live usb or dvd (cd) and use gparted (I am sure it is on the live cd) to remove the xp partition and to resize the ubuntu one. the partitions need to be unmounted thats why you need a live usb/dvd.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, that makes sense. Well I am in the process of backing up any usable files I have on that partition, (I don't think it would make much sense to keep any of the programs). I will try to update after this process. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments above you can use gparted, which can be installed by typing `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

If the Ubuntu partition and XP partition are next to each other, they can be made into one by deleting the XP partition and extending the Ubuntu to use the free space. You will receive a disk check error when you boot ubuntu because it will detect the drive change, but don't worry, nothing is wrong. Just let it run through.

It will depend on the order. For example if the XP partition occurs before the Ubuntu partition then the free space cannot be added because partitions are extended from the back end, meaning you will need to move (you can do this in gparted) the Ubuntu partition forward then extend it. Doing so however will prevent you from being able to boot ubuntu so make sure you know how to fix a grub entry (I don't or I would have typed it here).

Additionally the placement of your Windows 7 partition is important. For example if Windows 7 is the first partition on the drive then it's ability to boot won't be affected by changes to partitions behind it. However if XP and Ubuntu are installed before Windows 7 and you delete one of those partitions it could prevent Windows 7 from booting. Before you attempt anything I strongly recommend you post a screenshot of gparted so that whom-ever assists you can see where everything is, and you should state wether or not you have a Windows 7 installation disc.

Comment: **WARNING** You shouldn't/can't move or edit your root partition while it's mounted and running your OS!! Make sure you have a backup of your important data before attempting anything, and then use gparted from a live CD rather than trying to run it from your working Ubuntu partition.